# How to plot time series in python pandas and seaborn?

Tags: pandas, seaborn, timeserieschart

I have a dataFrame with multi-level columns

```
Name         North    South    East     West
date       A    B     A   B    A  B     A  B  
1-1-2010   10  20    30  40   50 60    70 80
1-2-2010   15  25    35  45   55 65    75 85

1-12-2010  115  225  335 445  555 665  775 885
```

I want to plot line plot and bar plot  in python pandas and Seaborn

Comment: And ... where are you stuck? Have you tried the docs, existing examples, etc? Please see [ask] and [reprex].

Comment: I am so sorry and could you please ,"BigBin"  show me step by step to write my question in acceptable format as you did